# Grant a user permission to read raw packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am running a program that reads raw IP packets, which seems to require root permissions. Is there a way I can grant permission to read raw IP packets to a user?

I am running Arch Linux and the C program I'm running creates its raw socket like this:

```
int fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use raw sockets process should have `CAP_NET_RAW`. You can read how to use capabilities in `man 7 capabilities`.

If your filesystem and kernel have xattr(extended attributes) support enabled, you can use `setcap` on executable. Alternatively you can use `sudo` or set sticky-bit for executabe(which is not that different from sudo).

Upd: I see... Actually, in linux it is possible to set capabilities of any process(not a file), but I don't know any existing utility that does that. If you read `man 2 capset`, you may notice PID inside cap header struct. Process that have `CAP_SETPCAP` can set capabilities of other procesess.

If PAM is installed on your system, you can with help of pam_cap set capabilities for user. Config is located in `/etc/security/capability.conf`.

Comment: Alex, have you seen update?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to grant this permission to a user.

However, it is possible to grant this permission to an executable file:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw=ep' ./some-executable
```

This will only work if `./some-executable` is a binary. It will not work if some-executable is a script.